# UICollectionView scroll issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, cell

I've got an UICollectionView with cells in it (no own cell class).

- When I try to scroll (always vertically only) the collectionView by touching outside the cells, the collectionView will scroll.
- When I try to scroll by touching the cell (while the scrollView isn't moving), It wont respond at all.
- But it does respond while it's scrolling. What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your collection view is not delay and not cancel the content touch. You should set `delaysContentTouches` and `canCancelContentTouches` properties to `YES`